# urge someone towards / urge towards

Tags: phrases

I looked it up online and found a sentence:

She began urging him towards the front door.

So we have “urge somebody towards”.

I’m wondering if I can say:

He’s urging towards the bus.

Or do I have to say:

He’s urging himself towards the bus.

Comment: I probably wouldn't say either one of those – certainly not the first one – but I would urge you to check out [ell.se].

Answer (score 1):

Whilst grammatically correct I don't think any native English speaker would say 'urging himself'; most often it is used when someone is trying to get someone/thing *else* to perform the action. We urge our horses to gallop harder, our team mates to try harder.

Comment: What about “hastening towards”? Like in the following sentence: He stumbled a lot on his way hastening towards the train. Does this sentence make sense and sound natural to you?